# How do you find out about new Java technologies, tools and specifications?

Tags: java

One of the major challenges for any java developer is try to keep in pace of development of the language and new tools. Java is evolving all the time and it happens often that I hear from a friend or colleague about some useful tool I had never heard of before.

I'd love to hear about how people find out when new java specs come out or an interesting, new tool is released? For example, what java blogs do you follow?

Answer (score 58):

Listen to the [Java Posse](http://javaposse.com/) podcast. It is fun, it is relevant and gives a great feel of  the Java (and wider JVM) community. It also has sections on Scala, Groovy, Android and (from time to time) Clojure.

Look for it on iTunes or your other podcatcher of choice.

Comment: +1 Java Posse, and the Java Ranch Journal javaranch.com/journal/

Comment: Sounds interesting, but this unfortunately doesn't reach the deaf audience, like me. There are no subtitles.

Comment: Nice find. Is there any 'best of' section, or recommendations for first time listeners? There are over 300 podcasts and I'm sure there are some gems there.

Comment: I especially like the Roundup sessions and the interviews. The newscasts are great, but as news, it has a limited  shelflife.

Comment: @BalusC there are unfortunately no full transcripts of JavaPosse, but you can still find all the news items and links on http://www.javaposse.com

Answer (score 20):

Keep reading questions and answers on Stackoverflow. You'll learn something new almost daily.

Comment: Though if something comes out which works first time with no bugs and excellent documentation, so that no-one needs to ask a question on it, then you'll miss it.

Comment: One could answer it as a solution.

Comment: @Pete not necessarily true, as there are plenty of "What is a good tool for this type of problem?" questions

Comment: @Pete, did you have any particular product in mind?

Comment: @Pete you would need an excellent documentation, in almost all languages, and the *excellent* programmer that not only reads the documentation but also understands it. A lot of questions in SO (and other sites) are about simple *problems* that are easily solved reading the *standard* documentation*.

Answer (score 6):

Another blog I can recommend: http://infoq.com/

In general blogs and **twitter** are very good, if you come across a good coder or project, start following his/it's blog or twitter. To get you started, [here's](http://twitter.com/statebox/computarmatron) whom I follow on twitter for computer related stuff

I tend to browse directories like http://java-source.net/ and http://www.manageability.org/blog/java regularly.

Finally, I follow RSS feeds of http://freshmeat.net/tags/java-libraries and http://freshmeat.net/tags/java

HTH

Answer (score 5):

http://www.theserverside.com/ has daily updates on new java/j2ee tools, resources and useful features/tutorials once in a while. That and SO are my daily visits.

and on a lighter note - http://thedailywtf.com/ :)

Answer (score 3):

Attend your local JUG meetings.
Find your group here:
http://java.net/jugs-list

Comment: or here: http://www.ibiblio.org/java/usergroups.html

Answer (score 3):

I follow articles on [Dzone](http://www.dzone.com/).

Answer (score 2):

I find [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/) specifically the Java zone a good place to keep up with Java and the broader developerWorks site useful in keeping up with IBM related technologies.

Answer (score 2):

my favorites :

1. [Dzone Refcardz](http://www.refcardz.com/)
2. [java specialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/)

i hope these can help you , i got a lot from them

Answer (score 1):

[javablogs.com](http://javablogs.com/) is quite helpful. It's some kind of blogs aggregator, 'blog community' for blogs which discuss Java technology regularly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should follow blogs. Search for Java blog feeds with for example Google Reader, and add them. Then you'll get the latest news in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [In Relation To](http://relation.to/) actively. It contains the blogs from JBOSS employees. Following Oracle blogs makes also sense.

Answer (score 0):

To keep updated your self with new technologies or tools, you can subscribe to RSS feed.
Can subscribe to any tool new letters, google news. Follow some bolgs. Use google reader.
you can participate in any mail group. This will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

JavaOne is a great conference if your employer will spring for it (it's rather expensive, esp. if you're not already located on the west coast).  It has a good mix of practical and higher-level, five-years-in-the-future stuff.  It helps me to have a solid block of time away from the details of work, so I can focus just on exploring new technologies and ideas.

They're also planning some worldwide JavaOnes in places like India this year.

Coolest single bit of technology I found out about there: http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/

Comment: did you know: west/east-coast isn't the end of the world!

Comment: @Chris: Quite so.  Edited to mention world-wide JavaOne.

Answer (score 0):

A bit *ancient*, not network based:
spend time (have lunch) with fellow  workers, speak about your duties, his problems, any hidden features of the used programming language you/he came across (from SO maybe), about the best IDE, ..., new games (ups, not working the whole time :-) )